# SelectedItem of DropDown in asp.net always shows the same value no matter what is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist control of asp.net.I want to track the item selected in the dropdownlist. Let me show what i have done.

This is DropdownList control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Dd_Cat" runat="server" 
         DataValueField="CatId" DataTextField="CatName" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="wtf"  >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the code behind used to populate the `dropdownlist` from database.

```
protected void bindDropdown()
{
   string mystr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mystr);
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddCat", con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", "select");
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
   Dd_Cat.DataSource = ds;
   Dd_Cat.DataBind();
   con.Close();
   con.Dispose();
}
```

The `onselected` property of `dropdownlist` control:

```
protected void wtf(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string st = Dd_Cat.SelectedValue;
}
```

This always show the value "1" nomatter what is selected.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you call `bindDropdown` in `Page_Load` without using `!IsPostBack`-check. Then you load always the default values and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event isn't triggered.

So use this instead if `EnableViewState` is set to `true`(default):

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // page is loaded the first time, load from database
        bindDropdown();
    }
}
```

Read: [`Page.IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)